# set of objects in avro schema

Tags: java, avro

I have the following field defined in schema. When I generate java objects using avro plugin, I get synonyms defined as "java.util.List". Is there anyway I can force plugin to generate "java.util.Set" in some cases?

```
               {
                "name" : "synonyms",
                "type" : {
                  "type" : "array",
                  "items" : "string",
                  "java-class" : "java.util.Set"
                }
```

Here is the relevant part of generated class. Not sure why the @deprecated annotation is generated..!

```
@Deprecated public java.util.List<java.lang.CharSequence> synonyms;
```

bump..

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to your question?